# не работает cкрипт авторизации php

Tags: php

Не работает скрипт. Данные из базы выводит, но дальше-стоп. Не сравнивает данные.
 если распечатать, то получаю-
81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055 - klimff@mail.ru - klimff@mail.ruпароль введён неверно .Что не так в ск

```html
<?php
 

$db = @mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'car.local') or die('ошибка соединения');

mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8") or die('Не установлена кодировка');

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
if (!empty($_POST["button_auth"])) {
 
 $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
 $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
 
 
 
 
 }
 //$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
 $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
 $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
 
 $email = $myrow['email'];
  $password = $myrow['password'];
 
 
 //echo $myrow['password'], ' - ', $password;
  //echo $myrow['email'], ' - ', $email; 
  //print_r($myrow);
 
 if($email == $myrow['email']){
  if($password == $myrow['password']){
   echo "Привет!";
  }
  else{
   echo"пароль введён неверно";
  }
 } 
 
?>



  <h2>Заполните форму</h2>


  <form name="auth" action="" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>E-mail:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Пароль</td>
        <td>
          <input type="Password" name="passwod">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <input type="submit" name="button_auth" value="Войти">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

рипте?

Answer (score 1):

Ачипатку устраните, да? И все заработает...

```
<input type="Password" name="passwod">
```

но

```
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
```

Нескладушки, однако.

P.S. Если что не так работает, как ожидается, - первым делом надо глянуть входящие данные. Для этого прекрасно подходит функция [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php). Вставили бы Вы в начало кода для отладки

```php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

и смогли бы самостоятельно увидеть несовпадение имени поля input и индекса $_POST.

**Update 1**

По обновленному коду - удалите строки

```php
    $email = $myrow['email'];
     $password = $myrow['password'];
```

`$email` и `$password` - это данные, введенные пользователем. Зачем же их затирать данными из базы, а потом сравнивать с самими собой? Когда делаете правку кода, даже если по ответу на свой вопрос здесь, всегда переспрашивайте себя: зачем? что это изменит в работе скрипта? Не стоит бездумно копипастить из ответа в свой код, так можно такого наворотить, что 5 экспертов (*это я не про себя, если что!*) не разрулят.

**Update 2**

Во вставленном в вопрос коде Вы снова ачипатались в имени поля `<input>` для ввода пароля. Ниже приведен код, который **должен** работать. Я изменил форматирование кода, выстроил правильную "лесенку" отступов, и код стало читать намного проще. В нем есть еще как минимум один "подводный камень" - запрос к базе и вывод сообщения об успешном или неуспешном вводе пароля выполняется не только когда нажата кнопка "войти", а в любом случае при выполнении скрипта. Но это Вы поправите сами, не буду лишать Вас маленьких радостей.

```php
<?php
echo '<pre>$_POST = ';
var_dump($_POST);

$db = @mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'car.local') or die('ошибка соединения');
mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8") or die('Не установлена кодировка');

if (!empty($_POST["button_auth"])) {
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
}

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

echo "\nEmail из базы ", $myrow['email'], ', Email из запроса ', $email; 
echo "\nПароль из базы ", $myrow['password'], ', пароль из запроса ', $password;

if ($email === $myrow['email']) {
    if ($password === $myrow['password']) {
        echo "\nПривет!";
    } else {
        echo "\nпароль введён неверно";
    }
}
echo '</pre>';
?>

  <h2>Заполните форму</h2>

  <form name="auth" action="" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>E-mail:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Пароль</td>
        <td>
          <input type="Password" name="password">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <input type="submit" name="button_auth" value="Войти">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Всё исправил , в итоге получаю постоянный "Привет* при любом заполнении полей авторизации. Хоть какой аброкадаброй.

Comment: @николай, Вы в полтергейст, Деда Мороза и Пиноккио верите? Я - нет. **Чудес не бывает.** Так что тут одно из двух: либо Вы в вопросе привели **не тот код, который запускаете**, либо Вы неверно интерпретируете написанный Вами код или результаты его выполнения. Обновите вопрос - вставьте в него тот код, который Вы сейчас запускаете на выполнение. И да, вот еще что: использовать `htmlspecialchars()` для поля пароля - плохая идея. Например, он заменит символ "<" в введенном пароле на "&lt;", а Вы неделю будете ломать голову - из-за чего пользователь не логинится?

Comment: Код забил по новой

Comment: Обновил ответ с учетом свежеприведенного кода.

Comment: Удалил. Но толку нет.

Comment: @николай Обновил ответ.

Comment: Принято. Отвечать не в лом. Не желал Вас как-либо обидеть. Тогда, если не посчитаете это для себя излишним, примите пару советов для "чайника" по отладке кода. 1. Придерживайтесь единообразного форматирования кода, правильная "лесенка" вложенных блоков упрощает понимание кода. 2. При любых непонятках с выполнением кода в ключевых точках (на развилках if, в местах появления сообщений об ошибках и т.п.) проверяйте значения используемых переменных, желательно функциями var_dump() или var_export() - они показывают не только значение, но и тип переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно , у тебя произошел конфликт с переменными , посмотри внимательней как ты написал условия

```
if($email == $myrow['email']){
    if($password == $myrow['password']){
        echo "Привет!";
    }
    else{
        echo"пароль введён неверно";
    }
}
```

то есть $email == $myrow['email'] , то есть в $email у тебя хранится email и в этой же переменной хранится пост запрос с формы!
И вообще для чего тебе 1-я проверка??? Там можно и без этого ты уже запрос сделал!
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

```
$result_email = $myrow['email'];
 $result_password = $myrow['password'];

    if($result_password == $password){
        echo "Привет!";
    }
    else{
        echo"пароль введён неверно";
    }
```

Вроде бы так , попробуй!:)

Answer (score -1):

Не было выполнено присвоение данных вытащенных из БД переменным $email и $password.
$email = $myrow['email'];
$password = $myrow['password'];

Comment: Всё исправил , в итоге получаю постоянный "Привет* при любом заполнении полей авторизации. Хоть какой аброкадаброй.

Comment: Переменные $mail и $password содержат оригинальные данные, полученные из запроса. Их надо сравнивать с тем что в базе, а не им присваивать то, что в базе. Иначе будет всеобщее "true forever". Если @николай внес эти правки в код, то его `получаю постоянный "Привет*` уже объяснено.

Comment: И как это записать?

Comment: Лучше всё-таки приравнять их к обычным переменным, а не обращаться постоянно к массиву.